# $\mathbb{Q}$-rational points in the affine and the projective spaces

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Ler $k$ be a field of characteristic zero. Let $\mathbb{A}^{n}(k)$ and $\mathbb{P}^{n}(k)$ be respectively the affine and the projective spaces over $k$ equipped with the Zariski topology. My questions are

1. Is the set of $\mathbb{Q}$-rational points of $\mathbb{A}^{n}(k)$ Zariski-dense in  $\mathbb{A}^{n}(k)$?
2. Is the set of $\mathbb{Q}$-rational points of $\mathbb{P}^{n}(k)$ Zariski-dense in  $\mathbb{P}^{n}(k)$?

Comment: The Zariski closure of $S \subset \mathbb{A}^n_k$ is $V(I(S))$. So what is $I(S)$ and what is $V(I(S))$

Comment: @reuns Thanks. I got it. In fact the field of rational numbers is infinite, so only the zero polynomial can have value zero on all rational points.

Comment: $\{ (0,x_2,\ldots,x_n)\}$ is infinite too but many polynomials vanish on it. The infinite argument works only for $n=1$.

Comment: @reuns $x_1$ can vary over all rational numbers and then by an inductive argument and varying the next variables we reach a zero polynomial.

Comment: So you meant for $p(a_1,\ldots,a_{n-1},t)\in k[t]$ to vanish on $\mathbb{Q}$ we must have $p(a_1,\ldots,a_{n-1},t) = 0$.

Comment: @reuns Exactly.